# How can I hide my navbar on the homepage and make it only visible once the user has logged in?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, higher-order-components

I'm making a react app, I made a navbar and It renders in all of the components and I only want it visible in one, I made a HOC function but It still doesnt work correctly.

Higher Order Components

this is my navigation component

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";

const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <div id = "navlinks">
            <NavLink to = "">PROMOS</NavLink>
            <NavLink to = "" >Nueva Orden</NavLink>
            <NavLink to = "" >Ordenes</NavLink>
            <NavLink to = "">Menú</NavLink>
            <NavLink id = "logout" to = "/" >Cerrar Sesión</NavLink>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navigation;
```

and this is is my router

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter , Route} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Menu from "./components/Menu";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";


class App extends Component { 
  render() {
    return (
     <BrowserRouter>
   <div>
   <Navigation/> 
     <div>
      <Route path= "/"  component = {Home} exact /> 
     <Route path= "/Menu"  component = {Menu}/>
     </div>




   </div>
     </BrowserRouter>
    );

} 
}

export default App;
```

and my HOC component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const LoaderHOC = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class LoaderHOC extends Component{
      render(){
          this.props.Navigation.length === 0 ? <div className = 'Loader'></div> : <WrapperComponent {... this.props}/>
      }
    }
}

export default LoaderHOC;
```

Comment: I suppose you have a way to determine whether your user is loggedIn or not. Suppose, you have store the information in `isLoggedIn` variable, than you can do following to hide navigation if user is not logged in,
`{ isLoggedIn && <Navigation /> }`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have a way to determine whether your user is loggedIn or not. Suppose, you have store the information in isLoggedIn variable, than you can do following to hide navigation if user is not logged in,

```
{ isLoggedIn && <Navigation /> }
```

But once your application grows, I suggest you to make different routes depending on the public/private state.

1. Create a PrivateRoute.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";

class PrivateRoute extends Component {

  render() {
    // use your own logic here
    const isLoggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      return <Redirect to='/' />;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation />
          // your private route
      </div>

  }
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

2. create your PublicRoute.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class PublicRoute extends Component {

    render() {
       <div>
          // your all public route
      </div>

    }
}

export default PublicRoute;
```

3. Now Just include those into your main file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter , Route} from "react-router-dom";
import { PublicRoute, PrivateRoute } from './routes';
import './App.css';
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Menu from "./components/Menu";



class App extends Component { 
  render() {
    return (
     <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <PublicRoute />
          <PrivateRoute />
         </div>
     </BrowserRouter>
    );

} 
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `HOC` for this.

You must have store somewhere that user is `loggedIn`, if not I would suggest you to use a [`localStorage`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) like,

```
localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", true);
```

**Note:** To setup a `localStorage` you don't need any extra configuration.

In your router you can use this to hide your `component`,

```
{localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") && <Navigation/>}
```